# In PHP is faster to get a value from an if statement or from an array?

Tags: php, optimization, benchmarking

Maybe this is a stupid question but what is faster?

```
<?php

function getCss1 ($id = 0) {
    if ($id == 1) {
        return 'red';
    } else if ($id == 2) {
        return 'yellow';
    } else if ($id == 3) {
        return 'green';
    } else if ($id == 4) {
        return 'blue';
    } else if ($id == 5) {
        return 'orange';
    } else {
        return 'grey';
    }
}

function getCss2 ($id = 0) {
    $css[] = 'grey';
    $css[] = 'red';
    $css[] = 'yellow';
    $css[] = 'green';
    $css[] = 'blue';
    $css[] = 'orange';
    return $css[$id];
}

echo getCss1(3);
echo getCss2(3);
?>
```

I suspect is faster the if statement but I prefere to ask!

Comment: [What you have tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Try it? you know you can time code execution in php right? Just try it :)

Comment: also, you forgot to add switch cases in there too. why not benchmark all options?

Comment: Here is a link on [how to check execution time](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/2058/determine-execution-time-in-php/)

Comment: Faster or not, getCss2 is going to be much easier to maintain. For a few nanoseconds, it's not worth the `if` statement mess. (Ever want to move this to a config file?)

Comment: @AndrewR and maybe also to change it to $colors = array('grey','green',.....)

Comment: I try and then I'll tell you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getCss1` (if statements) is roughly twice as fast `getCss2` (array access) from my benchmarks.

Results from `microtime()`:

```
getCss1 called 10,000 times in 0.016569852828979 seconds
getCss2 called 10,000 times in 0.037255048751831 seconds
```

Per the comments, I agree about maintainability of using a *translation* array. Accessing `$css` directly is significantly faster given the removal of function overhead and array redeclaration.

```
getCss1 called 10,000 times in 0.016607999801636 seconds
$css accessed 10,000 times in 0.0026898384094238 seconds
```

**Note:** Running PHP 5.3.15 on Mac OS X 10.8. I also varied call order `$id` to test execution paths.

Answer (score 3):

I timed it with:

```
$t = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < 10000000; $i++){
    getCss1(3);
}
echo "getCss1: ".(microtime(true) - $t)."\n";

$t = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < 10000000; $i++){
    getCss2(3);
}
echo "getCss2: ".(microtime(true) - $t)."\n";
```

If you define $css outside the getCss2 function, and use global $css, the function is still slower than getCss1, but a lot faster than the previous version:

```
$css[] = 'grey';
$css[] = 'red';
$css[] = 'yellow';
$css[] = 'green';
$css[] = 'blue';
$css[] = 'orange';
function getCss3 ($id = 0) {
    global $css;
    return $css[$id];
}

$t = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < 10000000; $i++){
    getCss3(3);
}
echo "getCss3: ".(microtime(true) - $t)."\n";
```

Results (Windows 7, AMD Phenom II: 3.6Ghz, PHP 5.3.3):

```
getCss1: 3.7735629081726
getCss2: 14.683212995529
getCss3: 4.2553169727325
```

Using different $id's:

$id = 6:

```
getCss1: 4.2732820510864
getCss2: 32.388185024261
getCss3: 20.429337024689
```

$id = 0:

```
getCss1: 4.3480041027069
getCss2: 14.638042926788
getCss3: 4.2784569263458
```

So the speed of the if's seems fairly independent of the position of the value, while array-access is much faster if when accessing 'low' keys.

Comment: Using less test cases, getCss3 is actually a little faster. Maybe some memory swapping is taking place with that many test cases?

Comment: If you define the $css variable like this `$css = array('grey','red','yellow','green','blue','orange');` and run it using the getCss3 you defined, it runs faster than getCss1.

Comment: Interesting, but now you say it; not unsurprising. I don't know much about PHPs internals though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to time it!

Keep those two functions in one file. After defining your functions start a timer on one, then on the other. Example:

```
// Run function 1
$time_start1 = microtime();
getCss1 (2);
$time_end1 = microtime();
$time1 = $time_end1 - $time_start1;

echo "getCss1 function executed in $time1 seconds\n";

// Run function 2
$time_start2 = microtime();
getCss2 (2);
$time_end2 = microtime();
$time2 = $time_end2 - $time_start2;

echo "getCss2 function executed in $time2 seconds\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

The only reason why the second function may be slower is because of time needed to access the memory.
However, the array can be stored in processors's cache so that time would be greatly reduced.
Also, the second function makes fewer jumps in the call stack.

In theory there is no way to tell because it would depend on current machine configuration and processor architecture.

If you do the speed test, be sure to take many tests and compare average speed values...

Answer (score 1):

Dont't forget that getCss1(3) always have to check 3 conditions. getCss(3) have to get the value of an array at position 3...

Definetly: accessing arrays is faster..

This was my test application:

```
function getCss1($id = 0) {
  if ($id == 1) {
    return 'red';
  } else if ($id == 2) {
    return 'yellow';
  } else if ($id == 3) {
    return 'green';
  } else if ($id == 4) {
    return 'blue';
  } else if ($id == 5) {
    return 'orange';
  } else {
    return 'grey';
  }
}

function getCss2($id = 0) {
  static $css;
  if ($css === null) {
    $css[] = 'grey';
    $css[] = 'red';
    $css[] = 'yellow';
    $css[] = 'green';
    $css[] = 'blue';
    $css[] = 'orange';
  }
  return $css[$id];
}

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
  $x = getCss1($i%6);
}
$end = microtime(true);
echo 'getCss1: ' . ($end-$start) . "\n";

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
  $x = getCss2($i%6);
}
$end = microtime(true);
echo 'getCss2: ' . ($end-$start) . "\n";
```

Comment: global is bad practice and slow and using static variables is even faster than if then else chains..

Answer (score 0):

Speed should depend on the value of `$id` because if it is 6 it will iterate through all if statements while getting indexed value from an array might be faster.

Answer (score 0):

First: if/switch statements aren't really dynamic and arrays are because they take up memory(yes i know the if statements probably do but it's soooo much smaller).

The if statements you don't have to hold variables in memory because you're not allocating anything to your server's ram (aka variables) except maybe the return value.

Versus

Every item in that array is going to be stored in memory first and then can be used in the key value method.

This is really too small of a scale to matter but, I've ran out of memory plenty of times creating dynamic key => value arrays from a database attempting to do various large things.  I recommend you use a switch statement for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct. If statement is faster, cause it's compares all the variants in the worthest situation. When you use an array, it needs time and memory to create all the variants in every situation.
But!
The variant with array is more readable and usable and if array not big and his values are constant (not result of functions!), it's better to use array-way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use switch instead of if also. Switch is faster then the if statement

```
switch ($id){
case 1: return "red";
break;
case 2: return "yellow";
break;
case 3: return "green";
...
}
```